# She came in , followed by a valet, carrying on his arm a big fur coat

Tags: participles, reduced-relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

Read the following

She entered, followed by a valet, carrying on his arm a big fur coat

The first comma is needed because there's a participle after it, but i don't get why the second comma was used.
Even if a non-restrictive phrase was supposed to be made there , one might have to add 'who is ' before carrying.

Do you think the second comma was necessary

Comment: I'd prefer _She entered, followed by a valet carrying, on his arm, a big fur coat._

Comment: When a direct object is mentioned that way , you don't have to have a comma .

Comment: I don't think the second comma is necessary.

Comment: The comma may have been added for the purpose of pausing - to let the reader know where to give a suitable pause while reading the sentence out loud.

Comment: To me, it's better without the comma. With the comma, it reads like *she* is carrying something, until we hit "his", and have to go back and re-read. Without the comma, it's clear the valet is carrying something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the second comma is not required.

> She entered, followed by a valet carrying on his arm a big fur coat.

is a perfectly valid and natural sentence. But neither is such a comma forbidden. Its presence is a matter od style, or is possibly intended as a hint to pause when reading aloud.